# Get an attribute from JSON object

Tags: javascript, regex

EDIT: As pointed out I have the following JSON object:

```
Object {name: "red", percent: 36, rgb: "rgb(216,28,63)"}
```

and I need to extract the percent number and the rgb numbers into 2 separate variables.

I have tried:

```
var noDivsToColour = JSON.parse(availableColours[k], "percent");
```

where availableColours[k] refers to my object but get the error 'Unexpected Token 0' - can anyone help please?

Comment: You haven't considered just parsing the JSON into an object?

Comment: Is this really the string or could you just use `JSON.parse()` and get your data from the resulting object?

Comment: Also, that's _not_ a JSON string. JSON keys need to be placed in double quotes (`"`)

Comment: What generated that string? It seems to me that it's an object description from somewhere.

Comment: from where I see it, the idea behind json is precisely NOT TO treat it as a simple string...

Comment: Are you really sure you have a string, and not an object? Could you show an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an actual JavaScript object instead of a JSON string. (It's a common misconception. JSON is used to transfer data structures between a client and the server, for example. It's not a data type by itself.)

You can access the elements in the object with the dot notation.

```
var percent = availableColours[k].percent;
var color = availableColours[k].rgb;
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not a JSON string nor a JSON object. Rather than trying to parse that string with a regex, you should solve the problem at the source (whereever that string was first generated).

You don't want the string:

```
'Object {name: "red", percent: 36, rgb: "rgb(216,28,63)"}'
```

You want this instead:

```
'{"name": "red", "percent": 36, "rgb": "rgb(216,28,63)"}'
```

Then you can properly [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it:

```
var json = '{"name": "red", "percent": 36, "rgb": "rgb(216,28,63)"}';
var color = JSON.parse(json);
```

And access the properties:

```
color.name;
color.percent;
color.rgb;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
var percent = obj.percent;
```

That will take your json string and turn it into a javascript object, from which you can easily extract the percent field.

EDIT:  As has been pointed out, this may not be a valid JSON string. The following will solve that.

```
var str = 'Object {name: "red", percent: 36, rgb: "rgb(216,28,63)"}';
var delimit1 = "percent: ";
var delimit2 = ",";
var tmp = str.substring(str.indexOf(delimit1) + delimit1.length);
var token = tmp.substring(0, tmp.indexOf(delimit2));
alert(token);
```

Comment: Any reason for using eval instead of parsing the JSON?

Comment: `eval` invokes the compiler. We don't use it, it lets the string provider execute code. Use `JSON.parse`

Comment: Changed it to use parse.

Comment: Also, from the look of it he already _has_ an object. `JSON.parse` will _fail_ on the input he has provided with an invalid JSON error.

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that what the OP has in the question is actually a string. Note that (at least in Chrome) if you `console.log()` an object you get "Object {...}"  just like in the question.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did - I assumed what I was getting was a string but I see now